# What is usage of this recuring generic class?

Tags: c#, generics

This code is compiled in visual studio, what is it's usage

```
public class MyClass<T>
   where T : MyClass<T>
```

Note `where T : MyClass<T>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and is usually used so that a base class can refer to its real type statically. This is done in an attempt to preserve type-safety so that parameter or return values referred to in the base class track the current type in the hierarchy e.g

```
public class Animal<T> where T : Animal<T>
{
    public abstract T GiveBirth();
}

public class Cat : Animal<Cat>
{
    public override Cat GiveBirth() { return new Cat(); }
}
```

Without the type parameter the `Animal` base class method would only be able to define the return type of `GiveBirth` to be `Animal`, which may reduce type safety for the clients.

It may be acceptible if you control the entire hierarchy and can ensure that classes supply the correct type parameter, but note that it can be abused e.g.

```
public class Cat : Animal<Dog> { ... }
```

Another downside is that any clients need to take account of the generic type parameter if they want to be applied to the base class e.g.

```
public static void Feed<T>(Animal<T> animal) where T : Animal<T> { ... }
public static void Feed<T>(T animal) where T : Animal<T> { ... }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but in what kind of problems we should use this pattern?

Comment: @RezaRahmati - I've added an example if that helps?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the curiously recurring pattern. Eric Lippert has [an excellent article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) on this, including why you should usually avoid it.

It might be extended like this:

```
public class MyChild : MyClass<MyChild>
```

The pattern doesn't really clue you as to *why* you want this generic. This is unlike most generics/constraints...e.g. if I have `List<Giraffe>` I can see the relationship; if I have `MyGeneric<T, U> where T : IComparer<U>`, I can see what `T` will do. With `T : MyClass<T>`, I really have no hints as to the relationships or usages here. Perhaps there's a...

```
abstract T Instance { get; }
```

...that you wish to have the stronger-typing of `MyChild` in the case of `MyChild`.

As an example of why this isn't so good, you could have `MyOtherClass : MyClass<MyChild>`, or you could have `MyGrandchild : MyChild`, neither of which are probably what you were trying to enforce.

Answer (score 1):

For types which will only have a single layer of inheritance from an abstract base type, use of the described pattern will make it possible for the abstract base type to include methods which, when called on any member of a derived type, will return a member of that derived type.  This can be a useful design feature, allowing for much cleaner caller code than would otherwise be possible.  The biggest problem with this design is that because .NET has no support for covariant generic class parameters, the approach won't work with multiple layers of inheritance.

Given `abstract class AnimalBase<T> where T:AnimalBase<T>`, with method `T Clone()` and `class Cat: AnimalBase<Cat>`, code could say `var newCat = someCat.Clone(); newCat.Meow();` rather than having to say `var newCat = (Cat)(someCat.Clone()); newCat.Meow();`.  Unfortunately, there would be no way to have a type `SiameseCat` properly derives from `Cat`, since the only way to have `mySiameseCat.Clone()`; return a `SiameseCat` would be to have `SiameseCat` derive from `AnimalBase<SiameseCat>`, but that would prevent it from deriving from `Cat`.

If rather than having a class constrain to its own type, one instead defines a generic interface and constrains to that, one may avoid such difficulties.  There would be no problem having `SiameseCat` derive from `Cat` while implementing `IAnimal<SiameseCat>`.  Further, interfaces are covariant, so a type which implements `IAnimal<SiameseCat>` could implicitly also implement `IAnimal<Cat>` [if `Cat` was an abstract type that didn't implement the interface itself].  Every derivative of the class would have to provide its own implementations of any methods whose return value varies with the generic type parameter, but from the caller's perspective, the interface types could behave perfectly with derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be guaranteeing the type is two-dimensional (if that term makes sense here).

For example: `Node<int>` would end up being `Node<Node<int>>`.

Comment: I think the compiler will show error because T in Node<int> is int but in Node<Node<int>> is Node<int>